# Reading Text from text file ant separating to variables

Tags: c#, list, variables, streamreader

I'm trying to set value to different variables from messy text.

Main Dishes
name;group;price;TAX;number;Id;;Fullname;Description;

Bigger modifiers
Name;group;price;TAX;number;Id;/some/additional/stuff

Smaller modifiers
Name;;price;TAX;number;Id;/some/additional/stuff

```
Text 

Omlet;Second Dishes;40,0000;;00027;326ef70c-8d29-4c63-94ce-0580f26f84ab;Omlet with chicken and mushroom sauce;;;;;
Onions;Vegetables;4,1000;21;00021;fe5bab77-72cf-474e-acbc-1562c2f6aa37;0/1/1/1/6;;;;
Tomatoes;Vegetables;4,2000;21;00022;180fa908-9428-444e-a1df-5b74a40def64;0/1/1/1/7;;;;
Day Soup;Soup;123,4560;9;10108;19674f89-a44a-423d-ae79-0fc020be8d72;;;;;;
Roast pork with sauce;Second Dishes;0,0500;21;1167;a929bf86-2b89-4af6-baf9-f37317e0d75f;;;;;;
Cucumbers;;0,5500;21;222;8e370b64-b1f8-4665-95ae-88327d877394;-/-/1/0/3;;;;;
Tomatoes with garlic;Vegetables;0,1100;21;00024;52d08882-41c2-4dc3-8c4b-998109b6aedc;-/-/1/0/3;;;;;
Salt;;0,3300;21;00025;39332fab-99e0-4663-a59a-fff0deab958d;-/-/1/0/3;;;;;
```

I have created a class

```
    class Food
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Group;
        public string Price;
        public string TaxPercent;
        public string Number;
        public string ID;
        public string Type;
        public string FullName;
        public string Description;
}
```

Can someone explain me how i suppose to seperate part to smaller modifiers and bigger ones? Should I  create new class or it is possible to work with one?
How should IF statement look like?

What i tried to so far

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Food> List= new List<Food>();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"TEST.txt"))
            {
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                
                {
                    string str;
                    string[] stringArray;
                    str = sr.ReadLine();

                    strArray = str.Split(';');
                    Food Dish = new Food();
                    Dish.Name = stringArray[0];
                    Dish.Group = stringArray[1];
                    Dish.Price = stringArray[2];
                    Dish.TaxPercent = stringArray[3];

                    List.Add(Dish);

                    textBox1.Text =displayMembers(List); 
    


} 
string displayMembers(List<Food> vegetables)
            {
                foreach (Food s in vegetables)
                {
                    return s.ToString();
                }
                return null;
```

```
 Out put 

TESTREADER.FOOD  //TESTREADER IS A FOLDER WHERE TEST FILE IS.
```

Comment: Could you describe what the exact issue is? Is it simply not working? Are you getting errors? Something else?

Comment: _"Because this code doesn't sort the information to variables."_ Can you add some examples of input / result pairs where you do not get the expected results?

Comment: First of all , i need someone to tell me if im going to the right way. It doesnt give me any errors , it's just simply doesnt work, doest sort text to variables. Seems that it just skips the text. I'm not sure, if you understand those split statements well, just take a look and tell me all the issues you see here and give me some advice or something i dont know :(

Comment: @Fildor Completely updated the question.

Comment: 1. `displayMembers` only ever returns the string representation of the first element in the list. 2. You shouldn't be doing I/O operations in the event dispatch thread (aka "main thread", aka "GUI thread", aka ...). But that's probably not the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public List<Food> getFoods()
    {
        List<Food> foods = new List<Food>();
        using (var fileReader = new StreamReader(@"file.txt"))
        {
            var line = fileReader.ReadLine();
            while (line != null)
            {
                string[] data = s.Split(';');
                line = fileReader.ReadLine();
                Food food = new Food
                {
                    Name = data[0];
                    Group = data[1];
                    (...)
            }

            line = fileReader.ReadLine();
        }

        return foods;
    }
```

Comment: How does it help?